# opening problem with youtube and hangout apps

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, youtube, google-hangouts

I am using Android 4.4.2 on Kyocera Hydro Icon.

Since a few weeks ago, I experienced problems with opening youtube and hangout apps (there may be other apps with the same problem, but I don't remember as they are not those apps that I use often). With hangout, sometimes I can still use text but not hangout dial, despite the error at opening.

My workaround for both apps is to uninstall their recent updates (I then still nned to install update for hangout but not for youtube to open them), and then I can open them successfully.

But soon, probably after automatic updates without my action,  everything is back to the original problems again.

What might be the cause and solution of the problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Radford found a fix the app crashing issue and his full solution is posted in the thread linked below. Kyocera did not include libpredtm.so in system/lib, so if you root your phone, you can place the copy of libpredtm.so that Ryan supplied and paste it into your system/lib directory. It has fixed the app crashes for a lot of users already.

http://androidforums.com/threads/google-play-services-not-working.944032/page-13#post-7124154