# Ways to call with Google Voice without mobile service and hangout?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-hangouts, google-voice

Are there ways to make and receive calls with Google Voice on Android 4.4.2 and Kyocera Hydro Icon,  but without mobile service and Google Hangout?

[My Google Hangout has some problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125563/opening-problem-with-youtube-and-hangout-apps), for which I am still looking for solutions.

My mobile service's signal isn't great in my apartment. So I am trying to use VoIP over WiFi.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there are any third-party apps/services that can do this since they were [blocked last year](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/04/reminder-third-party-google-voice-apps-shut-down-in-20-days/).

Answer (score -1):

you can use Grooveip app or Ringto app which is an alternative to hangouts and works same like hangouts.

Comment: you may want to add bit more info (like links to install the apps you mentioned and how to use them in brief) while writing answer.